# Is there a way to backup Wordpress Content without backing up Wordpress itself?

Tags: wordpress

I have an older Wordpress website that is now inaccessible (most likely due to an out-of-date plugin). Is it possible for me to backup the "Pages", "Posts", and "Plugin" data to use in a new version of Wordpress? Or would I have to bring the old site back to life and then update to the latest version of Wordpress?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming the plugins folder to old-plugins and then accessing the site; disabling all the plugins may get you back into admin and then you can upgrade. Once you've upgraded, you can move the old plugins back into plugins one by one and see which ones crash.

If you want to move to a new host and simply delete the old site and all plugins and themes, export the older site database with https://www.adminer.org/ or https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ or similar database admin tool. The database contains all your pages, posts, menus, plugin settings, etc.

Set up a new WordPress site with the latest core WordPress files and folders from a download, but **don't install** WordPress. Import your database, configure the wp-config.php file for the new database settings - i.e. database name, user, password, and table prefix - and visit the site with your browser. WordPress will tell you that the database needs to be upgraded, and it will do that. Then you have a site with your old content but the latest files and upgraded database.

You're basically moving WordPress to a new server, but not installing WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Keeping_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs